# How to use @GrailsTypeChecked and @GrailsCompileStatic

Tags: grails

I was interested to read about the new annotations in Grails which should in theory provide runtime performance improvements whilst still allowing dynamic dispatch however it seems to have no effect. What am I missing?

```
class MyService {

  @GrailsTypeChecked // or @GrailsCompileStatic
  def doSomething() {
    String name = missingVariable
  }
}

grails> clean
| Application cleaned.
grails> compile
| Compiling 1 source files.....
```

Everything compiles but blows up at runtime? I must be missing something because I don't really see how these new annotations could work. How will the compiler be able to work out what is a bad call and what is a bad call that can be ignored (i.e. a dynamic finder)?

I'm using Grails 2.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from Jeff's comments it seems there was a bug which prevented the @GrailsCompileStatic and @GrailsTypeChecked annotations from working when a class level @Transactional annotation was also present. I believe this is now fixed in grails 3.0.1 (Thanks guys!)

Answer (score 2):

That code shouldn't compile.  I have built a simple app and pasted your code     directly into that app and the code doesn't compile for me.  See     https://github.com/jeffbrown/grailscompilestatic.

```
| Compiling 8 source files
  [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:     startup failed:
  [groovyc] /Users/jeff/t/grailscompilestatic/grails-    app/services/demo/MyService.groovy: 9: [Static type checking] - The variable     [missingVariable] is undeclared.
  [groovyc]  @ line 9, column 19.
  [groovyc]        String name = missingVariable
  [groovyc]                      ^
  [groovyc] 
| Compiling 8 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
/Users/jeff/t/grailscompilestatic/grails-app/services/demo/MyService.groovy: 9:     [Static type checking] - The variable [missingVariable] is undeclared.
 @ line 9, column 19.
       String name = missingVariable
                     ^

1 error
```

> How will the compiler be able to work out what is a bad call and what
>   is a bad call that can be ignored (i.e. a dynamic finder)?

We have type checking extensions that collaborate with the type checker so when the type checker thinks it sees invalid code our extension is engaged and the extension gets the opportunity to turn the call into a dynamic call if the extension can recognize that it is something like a dynamic finder, which cannot be statically dispatched but is in fact valid at runtime.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for taking the time to look into this. I've compared my class to yours and I realised that I'm also using the Transactional class level annotation which seems to negate the GrailsTypedChecked or GrailsCompileStatic annotations. Please take a look at https://github.com/thobson/grailscompilestatic 

Is this a known limitation? if so maybe it needs to be documented (or maybe I have missed it!)

Comment: If I leave off the Transactional annotations the code compiles as I would expect but it seems that the .save() method on domain classes still cause problems i.e. new DomainClass().save() will give a compilation error although DomainClass.findByName() will be ok. Is this a known bug?

Comment: The Transactional annotation that is missing from the original question is significant.  That is not a known or expected limitation, that would be a bug.  I think I know what is probably going wrong.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues we can get that straightened out.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I should have pasted the entire class here, lesson learned! I will file an issue as requested

Comment: I think I fixed this yesterday. See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/beb434c9514f3f8d4ce8910afeb1c07380c2ecff.  Thanks for the feedback.